# Symfony 2.6 - Use MySQL for translate strings

Tags: symfony, language-translation, xliff

I'm new in Symfony 2 and I'm trying to translate multiple strings like menus and another static content and Symfony suggest to use Xliff. I want that the web admin can add or delete languages in the backend instead of edit the code. I know how can I do that, but I'm looking for a bundle that allows manage language like I want.

There is any bundle that allows manage language from the backend and add the translations for that elements that you use on the frontend dynamically?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [LexikTranslationBundle](https://github.com/lexik/LexikTranslationBundle).